# Codeigniter google-url-master library

Tags: codeigniter, loadlibrary

I am having trouble using this (https://github.com/gsouf/google-url) library as a codeigniter library.

I've downloaded the library from GitHub and placed it in this folder:
`application/libraries/google-url-master`

And created this file to setup the library as a codeigniter library:
`libraries/googleurl.php`

```
<?phpif (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');class GoogleUrl {

private $g;


function __construct() {
    require_once( APPPATH . 'third_party/google-url-master/autoload.php' );
    $this->g = new \GoogleUrl;

}
```

And then load if trough controller with this line: `$this->load->library('googleurl');`

But when I load the library it gives me this error:

`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65488 bytes) in \application\libraries\googleurl.php on line 11`

Looks like its in a loop, but I cannot figure out why this is happening.

I thought/hoped the anser of antoni would help me out, but no success so far: 
[How to Integrate SEOStats with Codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726314/how-to-integrate-seostats-with-codeigniter)

Thanks in advance,

Martijn

Comment: Try with composer. It's much more easier.

Comment: I can not see any class for the library,